# I have a visa to Spain from 11 August till 28 February, but I want to travel in December

Tags: visas, spain

I have applied for visa to Spain from the 11 August to 28 February which has been approved, but due to some family problem I want to travel on 15th of December instead of 11 August. Is that possible, or do I need to apply again even if it's still valid?

Comment: What type of visa is that? Typically, the validity would be specified on the visa sticker itself.

Answer (score 2):

Visas merely specify the time you're allowed to be in the country, plus sometimes the number of times you can enter (eg multiple entry visas).

What this means is that the visa is valid for entry any time from August 11th, but you must still leave before February 28th to avoid overstaying your visa.

(Note: this sometimes is different for work visas or working holiday visas, where you have to enter by a certain date to 'trigger' or 'activate' your visa)

Answer (score 2):

> I want to travel on 15th of December instead of 11 August.

Yes you can, if you hold a Schengen tourist visa (different for work related visas). There is no requirement that you need to travel on the 11th of August. You can travel any day until 28th of February, you exit the Schengen area by 28th of February. Going in the morning of 28th February and returning in the evening is also allowed, but be prepared to answer some questions at the immigration counter.

Comment: If the journey was to last from August to February (as opposed to short stays during this period), it can't possibly be a regular Schengen visa. Probably a long-stay national visa or, in exceptional cases, a limited territorial validity visa.

Comment: @Annoyed - It could be a Schengen C class(tourist) visa also. Many Schengen countries issue long duration visas, France mostly.

Comment: No, it couldn't. There is a distinction between validity and duration of stay. A Schengen visa can be valid for up to 5 years but never for stays longer than 90 days at once. Incidentally, a type C Schengen visa is a regular short-stay visa, not specifically a tourist visa.

Comment: @Annoyed - I mentioned about the duration of visa and not stay. C is a tourist visa. Any time I have applied, it has always been a C. The OP might have to clarify regarding what he(she) meant by his(her) statment `applied for visa`.

Comment: Yes, but that's precisely what my comment was about as the OP mentioned a travel between August and February, which makes your assumption that it is a Schengen visa questionable. On the other point, you have your logic backwards. If you want to do tourism you do indeed need a C visa but that does not make it a “tourist visa”. You would get a C visa for other purposes, too because that's the only type of non-transit Schengen visa.

Comment: @Annoyed - No I don't have my logic backwards, but you want to force your point down my throat. My assumption isn't questionable but your reasoning might be. C isn't a tourist visa, but why does mentioning it as a tourist visa(when every tourist is issued one) rattles you I cannot figure out. Generally if every tourist(short stay) is issued a C visa, primarily it is used for tourism. Yes it is used for other purposes too, but a tourist would generally apply for a C only.

Comment: It does not “rattle” me, I just thought it was a small detail that deserved to be mentioned and I don't understand why you feel the need to object so forcefully. One more time, it's completely true that a tourist would and should apply for a type C visa, I never disputed that. It's just that it does not make it a “tourist visa”. The point is that every academic visitor going to a conference and every business visitor would also get one. “Tourism” is just one of several purposes mentioned on the official application form, pointing out that tourists get one too is logically irrelevant.

Comment: More importantly, what makes your assumption questionable has nothing to do with that, it's merely the fact that the OP mentioned a trip between August and February. If he or she intends to stay in the area for the whole time (and not merely come and go for several short stays), that's not possible on a Schengen type C visa, for any purpose.